What is OWIN default user and password
I just created default WebApi project in Visual Studio which uses OWIN for authentication. What is its default user password as I need to get bearer token?
I also disabled OWIN from web.config by using following but now I am getting error:
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />

Error
No OWIN authentication manager is associated with the request.
I just want to simply access API for learning and need user/password or at least a way to disable OWIN.

You are more likely to find the answer at The OWIN website.

There isn't any. OWIN is an abstraction/set of interfaces, not a system. Project templates don't create default passwords either. Why are you using an ASP.NET Web API at all though? This is an old .NET Framework technology superseded by ASP.NET Core.
